# GraphQL typescript parameters types are incompatible

Tags: typescript, graphql, typescript-typings, react-apollo, typescript-generics

I am following a [react tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYhKsX9Alic&list=PLN3n1USn4xlnfJIQBa6bBjjiECnk6zL6s&index=11). However there seems to be a version mismatch and I cannot get my types to match. In particular, my code currently looks like this:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { graphql, ChildMutateProps } from "react-apollo";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import {
  RegisterMutation,
  RegisterMutationVariables,
} from "./RegisterMutation";

interface Props {
  children: (data: {
    submit: (values: any) => Promise<null>;
  }) => JSX.Element | null;
}

export class C extends React.PureComponent<
  ChildMutateProps<Props, RegisterMutation, RegisterMutationVariables>
> {
  submit = async (values: any) => {
    console.log(values);

    const response = await this.props.mutate({ variables: values });
    console.log("response: ", response);

    return null;
  };

  render() {
    return this.props.children({ submit: this.submit });
  }
}

const registerMutation = gql`
  mutation RegisterMutation($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    register(email: $email, password: $password) {
      path
      message
    }
  }
`;

export const RegisterController = graphql(registerMutation)(C);
```

Which results in a compilation error:

```
Argument of type 'typeof C' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Partial<DataProps<{}, {}>> & Partial<MutateProps<{}, {}>>>'.
  Type 'typeof C' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<Partial<DataProps<{}, {}>> & Partial<MutateProps<{}, {}>>, any>'.
    Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Property 'children' is missing in type 'Partial<DataProps<{}, {}>> & Partial<MutateProps<{}, {}>>' but required in type 'Readonly<ChildMutateProps<Props, RegisterMutation, RegisterMutationVariables>>'.
```

Possible solutions tried:

1. Introducing generic typings ( <ChildMutateProps<Props, RegisterMutation, RegisterMutationVariables>> ), for graphql call on the last line introduces more errors of similar nature.
2. Typing with "any" instead of RegisterMutation and RegisterMutationVariables introduces the same error, leading me to believe that something has changed with ChildMutateProps.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the working solution looks like, `react-apollo/graphql` has changed its typing.

```
// types
interface ComponentProps {
  children: (data: {
    submit: (values: any) => Promise<null>;
  }) => JSX.Element | null;
}

type WithMutateProps = ChildMutateProps<
  ComponentProps,
  RegisterMutation,
  RegisterMutationVariables
>;

// class definition
export class C extends React.PureComponent<WithMutateProps> { ...

// final controller
export const RegisterController = graphql<
  ComponentProps,
  RegisterMutation,
  RegisterMutationVariables,
  WithMutateProps
>(registerMutation)(C);
```